# After a tidyr join, ordering columns based on original data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

After doing a tidyr join of two data frames on each other, how can I order the returned columns based on the original data frame from which they came? I proposed a couple solutions below. The first feels clunky. The second probably isn't good practice. I think I'm missing something.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- data_frame(x1 = LETTERS[1:3], x2 = 1:3)
b <- data_frame(x1 = LETTERS[c(1,2,4)], x3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

# Not the order I want
left_join(a, b, by = "x1")

# This is the order I want
a %>%
  left_join(b, by = "x1") %>%
  select(names(b), names(a)[!(names(a) %in% names(b))])

# This works too.
right_join(b, a, by = "x1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you can do `unique(c(names(b), names(a)))`:

```
a %>%
    left_join(b, by = "x1") %>%
    select(unique(c(names(b), names(a))))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     x1    x3    x2
#  <chr> <lgl> <int>
#1     A  TRUE     1
#2     B FALSE     2
#3     C    NA     3
```